# C#/Unity3D - Function not working in the same way when called from different functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, udp

I am using Unity 3D as I client of a C# application using TCP and UDP sockets.

Here is a function:

```
public void updateCharacterPosition(CharacterPosition position, int characterId, int cnnId)
{
    if (Character.SceneLoaded != true)
        return;

    if (cnnId != ClientWorldServer.connectionId)
    {
        Debug.Log("HERE!");
        GameObject startPoint = GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/" + characterId.ToString());
        Debug.Log("HERE 1: " + GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline").transform.name);
        Debug.Log("HERE 2: " + startPoint.transform.name);
        GameObject endPoint = new GameObject();
        endPoint.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
        GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/" + characterId.ToString()).transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint.transform.position, endPoint.transform.position, Time.deltaTime);

        //Updating Clients ram of the character's position
        Character.characterDetails[characterId].characterPosition.x = position.x;
        Character.characterDetails[characterId].characterPosition.y = position.y;
        Character.characterDetails[characterId].characterPosition.z = position.z;
        //Destroy(endPoint);
    }
}
```

Here are two function which are calling this function:

The function receiving the TCP data:

```
    private void OnIncomingData(string data)
    {
        JsonData json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(data);
        string prefix = json.header.Substring(0, 2);

        if (prefix != "0x")
        {
            Debug.Log("Unknown packet: " + data + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            string header = json.header.Substring(2);
            int conId = json.connectionId;
            //Debug.Log("Header:" + header);
            switch (header)
            {
                default:
                    Debug.Log("Unknown packet: " + data + "\n");
                    break;
                case "000":
                    Debug.Log("Empty header received: " + json.header + "\n");
                    break;
                case "001":

                    if (connectionId == 0)
                    {
                        connectionId = conId;
                        Debug.Log("Connection ID: " + connectionId + "\n");
                        //After we have connected to TCP Stream now let's connect to UDP.
                        ConnectUDP();

                    }
                    break;
                    case "004":
                        DisplayCharacterSelects(json.data, connectionId);
                    break;
                case "005":
                    CharacterData charData = new CharacterData();

                    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json.data, Formatting.None);
                    charData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharacterData>(jsonData);
                    playerSpawner.SpawnPlayer(playerSpawner,charData);
                    break;
                case "006":
                    playerSpawner.SpawnOnlinePlayers(playerSpawner,json.data);
                    break;
                case "007":
                    CharacterLogout(json.data);
                    break;
                case "008":
                    CharacterPosition position = new CharacterPosition();
                    position.x = float.Parse(json.data["position.x"].ToString());
                    position.y = float.Parse(json.data["position.y"].ToString());
                    position.z = float.Parse(json.data["position.z"].ToString());
                    character.updateCharacterPosition(position, Convert.ToInt32(json.data["characterId"].ToString()), conId);
                    break;
                case "009":
                    character.updateCharacterRotation(json.data, conId);
                    break;    
            }
            Debug.Log("World Server: " + data + " TIME: " + Timer);

        }

    }
```

And here is the function receiving the UDP Data:

```
    private void UDPReceive()
    {
        _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv = (ar) =>
        {
            State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytes = _socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epFrom);
            _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv, so);
            Debug.Log("UDP World: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes));

            string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes);

            JsonData json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(receivedData);
            string prefix = json.header.Substring(0, 2);

            if (prefix != "3x")
            {
                Debug.Log("Unknown packet: " + receivedData + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                string header = json.header.Substring(2);
                int conId = json.connectionId;
                //Debug.Log("Header:" + header);
                switch (header)
                {
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Unknown packet: " + receivedData + "\n");
                        break;
                    case "001":
                        Debug.Log("Data received: " + receivedData + "\n");
                        break;
                    case "002":
                    CharacterPosition position = new CharacterPosition();
                    position.x = float.Parse(json.data["position.x"].ToString());
                    position.y = float.Parse(json.data["position.y"].ToString());
                    position.z = float.Parse(json.data["position.z"].ToString());
                    character.updateCharacterPosition(position, Convert.ToInt32(json.data["characterId"].ToString()), conId);
                    break;
                    case "003":
                    character.updateCharacterRotation(json.data, conId);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, state);
    }
```

What is happening. When `updateCharacterPosition()` is called from `OnIncomingData` which is the TCP listener the function is working 100% as intended.

However when the function `updateCharacterPosition()` is called from `UDPReceive()` the function `updateCharacterPosition()` seems like is stopping it's execution at `GameObject startPoint = GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/" + characterId.ToString());`

the lines:

```
Debug.Log("HERE 1: " + GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline").transform.name);
Debug.Log("HERE 2: " + startPoint.transform.name);
```

Are not showing any results. Like they are not there. No errors are showed in the Unity console like it can not find the object or something and still the `Debug.Log` is not showing anything. The only thing you can see in the console is the following line:

```
Debug.Log("HERE!");
```

Everything bellow this line seems to be not working and not firing any errors. Do you have any clue why this problem is happening and how can I solve it?

Both functions `OnIncomingData` and `UDPReceive` are in the same class.

Comment: UDP code is shown as using an Asynchronous receive method.The TCP receive method is not shown so I cannot answer question.What I can see is the UDP code is not correct.Whenever you send data the receive has to know where the data terminates using one of following 1) Ascii : Terminate message with known character not inside message 2) Ascii or binary : Precede message with a byte count 3) Ascii or Binary : Use fix size messages.TCP a send message has max length of ~1500 bytes and routers and server can split and join fragments according to spec.You may not receive entire message in one chunk

Comment: Here it is the complete UDP client: https://pastebin.com/q4iVFqKa

Comment: Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/kk4APJB7

Comment: The code has lots of issues.  Just adding sleep statements doesn't fix anything.  With TCP you have to make sure you receive the entire message before processing.  Your receive parsing code you are calling before you get the entire message.  Make sure you get entire message before calling the parser.  Your sleep statements doesn't do anything.  You should read TCP as fast as possible.  I prefer Asynchronous methods like your UDP.  Both UDP and TCP you must know where the end of the receive message occurs before parsing the message.

Comment: Okey I get your point on the TCP. However my trouble right now is the UDP. When data is received there the called functions from the parser seems to not work. Any idea why ?

Comment: Do you have the entire response before parsing the UDP message?  From your description of the issue it does not look like your received the entire response.  It is impossible just to look at the code and determine where the issue located.  You also should add exception handlers (try/catch) to capture any errors.

Comment: Yes I believe I do have the whole message because I can see the whole data transmitted. This function `updateCharacterPosition(CharacterPosition position, int characterId, int cnnId)` has three parameters. When I Debug.Log all of them all are there and correct. This makes me think all the data is there.

Comment: Transmitted does not mean the entire message gets received at the same time.  Even though you are sending the message out in one chunk you are receiving the message in multiple chunks.

Comment: Your UDPReceive() Event is driven by Windows Timers which does not wait for an end of message.  The longer the transmit message the greater the probability that the message will be split into chunks.

Comment: However when i make Debug.Log on the whole message i can see it's fully there.

Comment: For testing your parser just send the message you have in the Debug.Log and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why the UDP version isn't working, however I can shed some light on why certain portions of code aren't running.

Unity has what you can consider a "useful" feature where whenever an execution runs into an error that would otherwise end the program, it will instead end the current instruction set and continue at the next possible point without providing any errors to the console. As to why they don't provide an error, I couldn't tell you, but they don't.

So in terms of your program, the code is likely crashing at the line:

```
GameObject startPoint = GameObject.Find("CharactersOnline/" + characterId.ToString());
```

when trying to get the GameObject. In this case your code crashes, Unity ends the execution, and then continues onto the next possible thing it can run from the Monobehavior class, all the while pretending that nothing went wrong.

My suggestion for fixing this is to throw it into a try/catch block and print when it fails. Assuming I'm right you should be able to see a message print at that point and start debugging based on the data you can access at that time.